# One of my python file has increment numbers for a variable x how to import that variable x and run it on another python file so displays x increasing

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, import, python-import

- [This is the picture of the output of com1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMwsF.png)
- [This is output of com2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH7lm.png)

my first python file is named "com1" and it has a code to increment the value of x and y for every 3 seconds the code is:

```
x=0
y=0
for i in range(500):
      x = x+1
      print (x)
      y = y+1
      print (y)
      sleep(3)
```

my second code is named "com2" and i have used the following lines for the code:

```
from com1 import x
from com1 import y 
z = x + y  
print(z)
```

this isnt printing z which is x+y, but instead it is printing only the values of x and y
Can anyone tell me how to modify so that in my second python file com2 i can get an output of z ?

Comment: Are you sure you correctly imported the `com1` module? Because as it is written you would have waited for 1500 sec.

Comment: Can you show us your output? is unclear what you mean with *but instead it is printing only the values of x and y*. Changed the range from 500 to 2 and the sleep time to 1 and the script correctly print 4.

Comment: In `com1` you have written loop which contain sleep() method now unless `com1` 's code completely executed (loop for 500 * 3 secs delay = 1500 secs) you have to wait 1500 secs till `com1` finishes its execution so that it will gets imported in `com2`. Try substituting `5` in `range(5)`, then you will see after 15 secs you will get your output as Z=10.

Comment: I have added the pictures of the output
com2 is performing the sum only for the last values of x and y, how to make it perform for all

Comment: @DurgeshBalla what is your expected output ? like do you want to get results only from com2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this one satisfies your case

Contents of comm1.py

```
import time
from comm2 import inc

obj = inc()

for i in range(500):
    x,y = obj.increment()
    print(x+y)
    time.sleep(3)
```

contents of comm2.py

```
class inc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
    def increment(self):
        self.x = self.x+1
        self.y = self.y+1
        return self.x,self.y
```

Comment: Thank you Rohith its working now.

Comment: Why should this work? Please add explanatory text.